# How to return a empty cursor from a stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I have `OUT` parameter of a stored procedure as a `REF CURSOR`. Based on a particular condition, I would want to either return a result set (already implemented).

But how do I return an empty cursor when the condition fails? Without raising an exception? Just pasting pseudo code:

```
IF condition = true THEN
   OPEN OUT_CUR FOR 
   Select Some query

ELSE

   Return empty OUT_CUR

END IF
```

Answer (score 18):

you can try this

```
IF condition = true THEN
   OPEN OUT_CUR FOR 
   Select Some query;
ELSE
   OPEN OUT_CUR FOR 
       Select * from mtable where 1=2;
END IF
return OUT_CUR;
```

Comment: any other standard way to return empty set?

Answer (score 1):

```
IF condition = true THEN
   OPEN OUT_CUR FOR 
   Select Some query

ELSE

    OPEN OUT_CUR FOR select * from unnest(array[1,2]) arr where  false 

END IF
```

Comment: So far as I can tell, the only difference between this and @Satya's proposal from eight years ago is that you use `unnest(array[1,2]) arr where false` whereas Satya uses `mtable where 1=2`. Can you edit your answer to discuss why your approach might be preferable to Satya's well-established answer?

Comment: because no need any table for return  empty cursor.